# Fazer quebra de linha após ponto e vírgula ;

Tags: php, loop

Tenho um arquivo de texto (word) composto de quatro páginas com diversos endereços de email um do lado do outro separados por ponto e virgula.

Está dessa forma:

> exemplo1@email.com; exemplo2@email.com; exemplo3@email.com;
>     exemplo4@email.com; exemplo5@email.com; exemplo6@email.com;

Eu gostaria que ficasse assim:

> exemplo1@email.com;
>     exemplo2@email.com;
>     exemplo3@email.com;
>     exemplo4@email.com;
>     exemplo5@email.com;
>     exemplo6@email.com;

Eu acredito que dê para fazer utilizando php onde, será feito um "read file" que para cada ; (ponto e virgula) encontrado terá uma quebra de linha...

Gostaria de ajuda para conseguir isso.

**Meu código por enquanto lê o arquivo e imprime o resultado na tela....**

```
<?php
// Abre o Arquvio no Modo r (para leitura)
$arquivo = fopen ('emails.txt', 'r');

// Lê o conteúdo do arquivo 
while(!feof($arquivo))
{
//Mostra uma linha do arquivo
$linha = fgets($arquivo, 1024);
echo $linha.'<br />';
}

// Fecha arquivo aberto
fclose($arquivo);
?>
```

Comment: O que você já fez?

Comment: Por enquanto nada ainda, estou tentando ler o arquivo e imprimir o resultado...estou tentando montar o código

Comment: Monte alguma coisa, poste aí e diga qual sua dúvida específica para ajudarmos você. Não é legal pedir para fazer tudo por você.

Comment: @bigown, segue o meu código ... preciso agora fazer a quebra de linha

Comment: Já deu certo com o **str_replace**...foi mais fácil do que eu imaginava. Obrigado

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seria algo assim?

`str_replace(";",";<br>",texto);`

Vai substituir todos os `;` por `;<br>` do `texto`.

Comment: Deu certo amigo, muito obrigado.

Comment: No hora de imprimir a linha: `echo str_replace(";",";<br>",$linha)`. Tem um exemplo aqui: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp

Answer (score 1):

Tenho esse método completo que faz todo trabalho para separar os dados do email:

```
 function setEmail($stringMail)
    {
        $nstringMail = preg_replace('/\;/',',', $stringMail);
        $nstringMail = preg_replace('/(.*)\<|\>(.*)/','', $stringMail);
        $nstringMail = preg_replace('/\v+/',',', $nstringMail);
        $nstringMail = preg_replace('/\t+/',',',  $nstringMail);
        $nstringMail = preg_replace('/\n+/',',', $nstringMail);
        $nstringMail = preg_replace('/\,\,/',',', $nstringMail);
        $nstringMail = preg_replace('/\s+/','', $nstringMail);

            $dataEmail = explode(',', $nstringMail);
           if (!empty($dataEmail)) {
               foreach ($dataEmail as $stringValue) {
                  if (filter_var($stringValue, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
                         $emails[] = $stringValue;
                  }
               }
           }
        array_unique($emails);
        return $emails;
    }

$saida = setEmail('exemplo1@email.com; exemplo2@email.com; exemplo3@email.com; exemplo4@email.com; exemplo5@email.com; exemplo6@email.com;');

echo "<pre>";
print_r($saida);
```

Você pode conferir o código em ação por aqui:
http://ideone.com/7AzObO